# Distortions in multipanel plots

Tags: r, graph

If I plot a data and use lines to superimpose the same data points on the graph, I get the same data points. Lets say

```
     x<-rnorm(100)
     plot(x, type="p")
     lines(x, type="p",pch=2)
```

However, I have realized that there is a distortion in R plots when the same is done in a multipanel graph. It seems R is unable to recall the exact values on the y-axis when you plot the same data again. A simple code below shows the outputs from "plot" and "lines" are not the same.

```
  set.seed(1000)
  Range<-rbind(rep(0,4),c(100,100,1,100));thres<-70
  Ylab<-c("MAD","Bias","CP","CIL")

  X<-list(EVI=cbind(runif(10,0,100),runif(10,0,100),
     runif(10,0,1),runif(10,0,100)),
    Qp=cbind(runif(10,0,100),runif(10,0,100),runif(10,0,1),runif(10,0,100)))


   Plot<-function(x,Pch=1,thres)
       {

     par(mfrow=c(1,4),las=2)
        for(j in 1:4)
        {
      plot(x[,j],xaxt = "n",xlab="Estimator",
      ylab=Ylab[j],type = "p", pch = Pch, ylim=Range[,j])
      par(mfg=c(1,j))
       axis(1, at=1:nrow(x), labels=LETTERS[1:nrow(x)]) 


       if(j!=3){
         par(mfg=c(1,j))
         abline(h=thres,col=2)
         }else{
       par(mfg=c(1,j))
       abline(h=c(0.90,0.95,0.99),lty=c(2,1,2),col=rep(2,3))

       }
          }
  }

     Line<-function(x,Pch)
      {
        for(j in 1:ncol(x)) {
         par(mfg=c(1,j))
        lines(x[,j], type = "p", pch = Pch,col=2)
             }
       }


       lapply(X,function(dat)Plot(dat,thres=thres))

       ## First panel
       Line(X$EVI,Pch=2)

       ## Move to second panel
       Line(X$Qp,Pch=2)
```

What explains the distortions in the positioning of the points in the 3rd column? Note that, I have included the range of each data courtesy @WhiteViking  in the "Plot" function. However, the distortion keeps showing. Thank you

Comment: Now that I've seen the actual code that triggered the problem, I replaced my suggested solution with what I think is a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the ordering of 'plot' and 'lines'.

Code like this, with all 3 'plot' commands upfront:

```
set.seed(1)
X <- cbind(rnorm(20), 2 * rnorm(20), 3 * rnorm(20))

par(mfrow = c(1,3))

for (i in 1:3) {
  plot(X[,i])
}

for (i in 1:3) {
  par(mfg = c(1,i))
  lines(X[,i], type = "p", col = 2, pch = 3)
}
```

yields misaligment:

[image]

In the example above the first 'lines' command that get executed bases its scaling on the last 'plot' that happened. Since that had a larger vertical range than the first, the scaling of the 'lines' is incorrect.

Whereas structured like so:

```
set.seed(1)
X <- cbind(rnorm(20), 2 * rnorm(20), 3 * rnorm(20))

par(mfrow = c(1,3))

for (i in 1:3) {
  par(mfg = c(1,i))
  plot(X[,i])
  lines(X[,i], type = "p", col = 2, pch = 3)
}
```

it gives correct alignment of 'plot' and 'lines':

[image]

You'll probably have to rework your code to group 'plot' and 'lines' together for each sub-plot.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am doing a simulation study and I plot the values as and when one run gets done. It is not sequential as the latter example you gave. I may have to gather all results and then do the plots sequentially i.e each "plot" followed by "lines".  However, is there no other way to get the scaling done properly in the distorted one? I am grateful for the insight you have given.

Comment: @RichyMinkah I don't know a nice solution, sorry. But I'm only an R amateur... If you are under time pressure and just want this single graph *now*, you might get it working with a really ugly hack. Scale the data passed to 'lines' for the third panel up so that it matches the scale of the three others. So: lines(x[,j]*ifelse(j==3,100,1), type = "p", pch = Pch,col=2) in your Line function. I suspect that'll work but it's a dangerous play...

Answer (score 0):

When the third column is converted to percentages, the ylim becomes uniform and hence there isn't such distortion. However, it will be good to get a way around it instead of such adhoc transformation

Answer (score 0):

`plot()` sets up a coordinate system via `plot.window` based on the range of the data. This information is apparently stored in `par(usr)` for the *latest* plot, which means that if you want to revisit older plots, you should store those usr values and reset them accordingly,

[image]

```
set.seed(123)
d1 <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))
d2 <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=10*rnorm(10))

par(mfrow=c(1,2),mar=c(2.5,2.5,0,0))
plot(d1, type="p")
usr1 <- par("usr")
plot(d2, type="p")
usr2 <- par("usr")

par(mfg=c(1,1), usr=usr1)
points(d1, col="red", pch=3)
par(mfg=c(1,2), usr=usr2)
points(d2, col="red", pch=3)
```